# True or false? For all $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ we have that det(A+B) $\neq$ det(A)$+$ det(B)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, determinant

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> True or false? For all $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ we have that
>   $\det(A+B) \neq \det(A)+ \det(B)$.

The statement should be false because whenever we get that $\det(A) =0$ and $\det(B) =0$, we will have that $\det(A+B) = \det(A) + \det(B)$.

More specific counter-example, let $n = 0$.

---

Is it alright like that or is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure that $\det(A+B)=0$ is necessarily true with these hypotheses. However, $\det 2A=0$.

Comment: We know that determinants behave nicely in a multplicative sense. The do not behave nicely in an additive snese. But for very special chooses of $A$ and $B$ it is possible to fluke the additive equation that you state, as EJ shows in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is right, but you can not fix $n=0$ if you want to prove the statement is false for all $n$.

You are right when you say a counter-example is sufficient.

For example, take the null matrix $A$ of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, and $B:=A$.

You have $\det(A+B)=0=\det (A)+\det(B)$, so the statement is **false**.